# Integral closure in the field of fractions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals

> I have the ring $R= \mathbb{Q}[x,y]/\langle x^7-y^3\rangle$. I want to eventually find out the integral closure of $R$ in its field of fractions.

Here's my current steps:

I take a parameterisation of $x^7-y^3=0$ as $x=t^3, y=t^7$ which means $R \cong \mathbb{Q}[t^3,t^7]$ (not precisely sure what I need to say here to justify this?).

Now I say the field of fractions of this is $\mathbb{Q}(t)$, because $t=\frac{t^7}{(t^3)^2}$ is in the field of fractions (is this sufficient?), which has integral closure $\mathbb{Q}[t]$. This means the integral closure of $R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[t]$. What do I need to say to show that the integral closure of $R$ is equal to $\mathbb{Q}[t]$? Any help appreciated!

Comment: How can it be equal? The variables are different. Isomorphic is all you get, but that's enough for almost any query, so what's the issue?

Comment: Also, you have a typo: It should be $x=t^3,\;y=t^7$.

Comment: Sorry for the slowness, so we have the integral closure of R is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[t]$.. is it equal to $\mathbb{Q}[y/x^2]$? and thank you, fixed. Also, does everything else in my solution follow fine? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, some of your statements need to be corrected. The integral closure of $Q[t^3,t^7]$ is $Q[t]$. The integral closure of $Q(t)$ is itself, not $Q[t]$.

Comment: No, the the integral closure of $R$ is not _equal_ to $Q[y/x^2]$. For one thing, $R$ is not a subring of $Q[y/x^2]$.

Comment: What's wrong with just isomorphic to $Q[t]$?

Comment: So the most we know is the integral closure of $R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[t]$?

Comment: As I said, that's good enough.

Comment: Great, thank you. Sorry, I wasn't trying to undermine you, I was just trying to ensure my answer was "complete" as possible.

Comment: If write $R=\mathbb Q[\bar x,\bar y]$, where "bar" denotes the residue class modulo the ideal $(x^7-y^3)$, then the integral closure of $R$ is $R[\bar y/\bar x^2]$.

Comment: Ok, I agree, if you mod out, you can express the integral closure as an actual  subring of the quotient field. But for any work with that integral closure, it makes sense to maintain the parameterization, i.e., i.e., regard it as Q[t] via the isomorphism..

Comment: I saw someone commented (not sure why its deleted now) about proving that $R \cong \mathbb{Q}[t^3,t^7]$. Would I say there's a map $\phi: \mathbb{Q}[x,y] \to \mathbb{Q}[t^3,t^7]$ with $\phi(x,y) = (t^3,t^7)$ and say via the first isomorphism theorem that $\operatorname{ker}\phi = \langle x^7 - y^3 \rangle$, so $R\cong \mathbb{Q}[t^3,t^7]$?